# Orientation of ridge

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, convex-hull

In **D**-dimensional *space* given a two simplicial (say, 2-dimensional *triangle* faces in D3 *space* for *tetrahedron*) adjacent *facets* **V** (visible) and **H** (horizon), defined by two arrays of **D** **D**-dimensional *points* **P<sub>V</sub>** and **P<sub>H</sub>**. The orders of elements in above arrays are strictly defined and, in turn, define an *orientations* of *facets* in *space*. Say, theirs indexes in *universal* set of the points **U** (which involved in geometric calculations) presented as two `std::list< std::size_t >`s. The *ridge* is **D - 1** dimensional boundary element of *facet* (say, 1-dimensional *edges* of tetrahedron in D3 *space*). To define which *points* are common for both *facets* I simply can do the following:

```
point_list visible_set_ = visible_facet_.vertices_;
point_list horizon_set_ = horizon_facet_.vertices_;
visible_set_.sort();
horizon_set_.sort();
point_list ridge_;
std::set_intersection(visible_set_.cbegin(), visible_set_.cend(),
                      horizon_set_.cbegin(), horizon_set_.cend(),
                      std::back_inserter(ridge_));
```

But during `std::sort` execution I lose an information about **codirectionality** of *ridge* **R**, defined as `ridge_` above, and the same *ridge* of any of both *facets*.

The **codirectionality** can be defined afterwards by means of calculation of swaps number, which minimally needed to perform a permutation from 1.) array of the *points* of the *ridge* in order as it presented in given array of the *points* of the *facet* of interest to 2.) produced array of the *points* of the *ridge* **R** itself. But I sure that there is overhead here.

Another way to defining the **codirectionality** is to calculate an *oriented square* of a two *facets* (one constructed from exclusive *point* (difference of the *facet* and the *ridge*) and then the *ridge* and one produced by simple modification of the *facet*: moveing exclusive point to the front, as it located in the first of the two *facets*).

How to perform an intersection of two unsorted arrays with fixed order of elements so, that the result array saves the order of elements as it presented in first (xor second) array. Is there such algorithm, having time complexity less than **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**? Especially interested the **STL**-aided implementation possibility.

Comment: What does the swaps number exactly mean? Can only adjacent elements be swapped or it is allowed to swap arbitrary elements?

Comment: @user2040251 I think in case of simplicial complex (**D - 1** facet or **D - 2** ridge) we can swap non-adjacent elemens (all they is linearly independent from each other). The swaps number means the number of flips in some sense. Really, the parity of the number of swaps makes sense in above application (only two **D**-dimensional halfspaces defined by **D - 1** facet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can use the following scheme. First, make the copies of your original arrays (call them `visible_set_for_sorting` and `horizon_set_for_sorting`). Then sort them. Then form the intersection in the following way:

```
std::set<int> intersection;
std::set_intersection(
    visible_set_for_sorting.begin(), visible_set_for_sorting.end(),
    horizon_set_for_sorting.begin(), horizon_set_for_sorting.end(),
    std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));
```

Now you can iterate any original array (`visible_set_` or `horizon_set_`), check whether the point is in `intersection` and form the resulting list in the needed order.

```
std::list<int> list;
for (int p : visible_set_)
{
    if (intersection.find(p) != intersection.end())
    {
        list.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

Complexity shouldn't be higher than O(N*log(N)).

Comment: Thanks, I already did it. But we can simply do `std::set< std::size_t > ridge_(horizon_.cbegin(), horizon_.cend());` in **O(n * log(n))**, then your circle.

Answer (score 1):

[My version](https://bitbucket.org/tomilov/quickhull/src/fc29d907ad7e3ef3030d62e8af49fe5859f60982/include/quickhull.hpp?at=master#cl-415) replaces the exclusive point by furthest point keeping its order as in original visible facet. Newfacet (in terms of original [qhull](http://qhull.org/) implementation) created as result:

```
point_set horizon_(horizon_facet_.vertices_.cbegin(),
                   horizon_facet_.vertices_.cend()); // n * log(n) +
auto const hend = horizon_.end();
point_list ridge_;
for (size_type const p : vertices_) { // n *
    auto const h = horizon_.find(p); // (log(n) +
    if (h == hend) {
        ridge_.push_back(apex);
    } else {
        ridge_.push_back(p);
        horizon_.erase(h); // const)
    }
}
```